# Loop em PHP para criar um formulário dinamicamente

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

boa tarte.

Estou com dificuldade em criar uma função em php para criar uma lista de checkbox.

Quero preencher o atributo value e o conteúdo HTML de  com informações fornecidas pelo PHP, por meio de um loop.

O resultado final em HTML precisa ser semelhante a este:

```html
<form name="form" method="post" action="form.php">
<p>
<label>php</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="php"/>
</p>
<p>
<label>java</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="java"/>
</p>
<p>
<label>mysql</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="mysql"/>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que você tenha uma coleção:

```
$collection = [
   [
    'value' => 'php',
    'label' => 'php'
   ],
   [
     'value' => 'java',
     'label' => 'java'
   ],
   [
     'value' => 'mysql',
     'label' => 'mysql'
   ]
];
```

Bastaria fazer isso:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="form.php">
<?php if(count($collection)): ?>

<?php foreach($collection as $data):?>
  <p>
    <label><?php echo $data['label'];?></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="<?php echo $data['value'];?>"/>
 </p>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Opa beleza?

Para fazer o loop você tem que ter uma variável que já possua os dados que precisa, e dai você pode usar o foreach pra isso, passando no value o atributo que deseja:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="form.php">

<?php foreach($sua_variavel as $auxiliar) //neste caso, estarei pegando o valor de
//um array e atribuindo no VALUE da minha tag, mas você pode colocar 
//também uma variável que não seja um.

<p>
<label>php</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="<?php echo $auxiliar['key']?>"/>
</p>
<p>
<label>java</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="<?php echo $auxiliar['key']?>"/>
</p>
<p>
<label>mysql</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="<?php echo $auxiliar['key']?>"/>
</p>

?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

Repare que deixei as tags do form fora do PHP, pois se você quer algo dinâmico, suponho que tudo o que está dentro deste form será enviado para a função PHP que recebe o formulário.

Caso você queira deixar 1 formulário diferente para cada loop, basta deixar a tag  dentro do loop, porém tenha em mente que será necessário alterar o action dinâmicamente. (a não ser que queira enviar apenas uma informação de um dos formulários).

OBS: cuide também com os names, eles devem ser diferentes um dos outros (provavelmente terá que usar uma variável que concatena cada uma delas, para que quando o PHP receber o valor possa diferenciar). VOcê pode acrescentar um espaço a mais no teu array name="genero[1]", name="genero[2]", name="genero[3]"... Pra ser diferente um dos outros.